# Solving a system of nonlinear equations 2

Tags: equation-solving

Regarding this question:
[Solving a system of nonlinear equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60861/solving-a-system-of-nonlinear-equations)
When I try to solve the same system (with the code proposed in Daniel Lichtblau's answer) with different Right Hand Side values, Mathematica does not return any answer (while "fsolve" in Matlab gives me the exact answer as I am anticipating, that is: α1=3, α2=2, α3=1, β1=1, β2=1, β3=1)
I used the following code in Mathematica. Please let me know what is the reason?

```
M = {{α1, β3, β2}, {β3, α2, β1}, {β2, β1, α3}};

    Timing[
     sol2 = NSolve[{
       β1 - (β2 β3)/α1 == 2/3, 
       α2 - (β3 β3)/α1 == 5/3, 
       α3 - (β2 β2)/α1 == 2/3, 
       α1 - (β2 β2)/α3 == 2, 
       α2 - (β1 β1)/α3 == 1, 
       β3 - (β1 β2)/α3 == 0, 
       (4/3*Pi)^2 == 2.96^2*(CharacteristicPolynomial[M, x] /. x -> 0)}, 
       {α1, α2, α3, β1, β2, β3}]]
```

Comment: Is there a typo?: 1) The Matlab solution is not a solution to your system. Try `Block[{α1 = 3, α2 = 2, α3 = 1, β1 = 0.2, β2 = 0.2, β3 = 0.2}, equations /. Equal -> Subtract]` on your `equations`.  The first three equations have sides that differ by `-0.0000333333`.  2) You have more equations than unknowns.  Getting them to be consistent with machine numbers might be tricky.  You might have to solve the first six and then select the solution(s) that satisfy the seventh within a suitably chosen tolerance.

Comment: if I show the coefficients in Right Hand Side(RHS) with X and Z as follows:   ,β1 - (β2 β3)/α1 =X1, 
       α2 - (β3 β3)/α1 =X2, 
       α3 - (β2 β2)/α1 =X3, 
       α1 - (β2 β2)/α3 =Z1, 
       α2 - (β1 β1)/α3 =Z2, 
       β3 - (β1 β2)/α3 =Z3,   then there is a dependency between first 6 equations as following: (Z3^2/Z1)-Z2=(X1^2/X3)-X2  I think I have actually 5 equation instead of 6 and that's why I have added the last equation (it is a conservation of mass) and ...(please go to the next comment)

Comment: the above system has no problem in solving many cases (like: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60861/solving-a-system-of-nonlinear-equations) but, I have problem with these specific above mentioned values for RHS (as mentioned in this recent question above). I do not know, what should I do in this situation?

Comment: and why it is unable to solve the system only in some cases? @MichaelE2 Thanks for your reply. Would you please read two above comments and let me know your opinion?

Comment: @MichaelE2 since "fsolve" in Matlab is a numeric solver and an accuracy of -0.00003 as you mentioned above is acceptable for me (I can enhance it) by mentioning the Matlab results, I just want to say that the system has at least one acceptable answer that Mathematica does not give (please read the above comment as well)

Comment: In that case, try `NSolve[Rest[equations], {α1, α2, α3, β1, β2, β3}]`.  The dependency is really only a "near" one when the coefficients are approximate numbers, and at normal machine precision, *Mathematica* thinks the equations are independent.  The suggestion can be improved, but see if it seems right.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks again for your comment. By adding "Rest" to the set of 7 equations, it gives me 4 sets of answers, while previously Mathematica gave me 2 answers for these equations when I solved it with these values for α1, α2, α3, β1, ...: (3,1,3,1,1,1) Do you think it is normal that for some RHS values I have 2 answers and for some others 4 answers? Thanks alot

Comment: @MichaelE2 without "Rest", it returns two answers that both of them satisfy all the 7 equations. But, when I add Rest, it gives me 4 answers that two of them do not satisfy the equations and in fact they are not "answers" of my Eq. set. Why the Rest add two wrong answers? (If you want MORE DETAILS please read/run below code as well) Many thanks

Comment: M={{\[Alpha]1,\[Beta]3,\[Beta]2},{\[Beta]3,\[Alpha]2,\
\[Beta]1},{\[Beta]2, \[Beta]1,\[Alpha]3}};
Timing[sol2=
NSolve[{\[Beta]1-(\[Beta]2 \[Beta]3)/\[Alpha]1== 
     2/3,\[Alpha]2-(\[Beta]3 \[Beta]3)/\[Alpha]1== 
     2/3,\[Alpha]3-(\[Beta]2 \[Beta]2)/\[Alpha]1== 
     8/3,\[Alpha]1-(\[Beta]2 \[Beta]2)/\[Alpha]3== 
     8/3,\[Alpha]2-(\[Beta]1 \[Beta]1)/\[Alpha]3== 
     2/3,\[Beta]3-(\[Beta]1 \[Beta]2)/\[Alpha]3== 
     2/3,(4/3*Pi)^2== 
     2.094^2*(CharacteristicPolynomial[M, x] /. 
        x -> 0)},{\[Alpha]1,\[Alpha]2,\[Alpha]3, \[Beta]1, \
\[Beta]2,\[Beta]3}]] Please read above comment

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, Finally I need only one of the answers. In fact, two of them are the answers of my set, but only one of them is what I want and I am also thinking about a method to distinguish which one is my final answer,it is interesting for me how did you find that?!(Dear Michael, these equations are related to 3D equation of an ellipsoid (a water droplet)that I am working on.I have prepared a brief easy to read report from it in 6 pages,I will be more than happy if you can have a look on it and let me know your overall opinion.If you agree please give me your address h.banitabaei@gmail.com

Comment: (1) I don't have a good answer or suggestion at this point. The method using `Rest` seems to be viable though. (2) If you upload your report somewhere and give a link, I'll take a further look.

Comment: Very minor improvement on @MichaelE2 approach: First create expressions by subtracting right sides from left sides of the equations. Then can do `NSolve[Flatten[{Thread[Rest[exprs] == 0], 
   First[exprs]^2 < 10^(-4)}], vars]`. Advantage is it filters out the "parasite" solutions automatically.

Comment: @Hossein I will delete most of my comments from our conversation in a while, since I think I've included most of them in my answer.  You might consider doing the same for some of yours.  In your case, you might also consider adding some of them to your question.  I'm thinking in particular about the number of solutions, the Matlab tolerance, and anything else you think important.

Comment: My thought is that for now the method of @MichaelE2 is the best I can think of. Solve for all but the first equation (so it's neither over nor under determined), then use the first equation to rule out "bad" solutions. The problem is the system is not what's called a "complete intersection", and `NSolve` is not able to discern that it is consistent within a certain tolerance. If I get time I'll look into that but in any case `NSolve` is not now able to handle the full system.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for your comments. By having the following dependency relation for the system above (Z3^2/Z1)-Z2=(X1^2/X3)-X2, how can I find that the "first" equation should be ignored? (why not the 2nd?) and whether this means that the first equation doesn't add any new information to the system and I have, in fact, 7-1=6 independent (useful) equations? and What do you mean by ruling out "bad solutions"? Thanks again

Comment: By "bad" solutions I mean the ones that satisfy 6 but not all 7 equations. As for which equation you might initially discard, that's not so easy. I think it could be any but the last in this case (I have not checked that though). Might be a trial-and-error situation, I'm not sure.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I omitted the first 6 equations one by one and I got the following results(in the system of eqs shown in very beginning of this page,not in the answer section): If I omit equation No. 2 OR 3 OR 5 OR 6, nothing will happen in my answers and system still gives me two answers just like when I solve all the 7 eqs together.But, if I omit equation No. 1 OR 4, number of answers will increase to 4. It seems that eqs. No. 1 & 4 are more important than others. Do you think that this can help me in finding the desired answer (droplet) between two possible answers that the system returns?

Comment: Note: as you know, the first 3 equation is related to one projection view (first ellipse) and eqs. No. 4 to 6 are related to another projection view that provided through my second camera. An interesting issue is that equations 1 and 4 (that maybe are more important than other eqs), are corresponding to X1 and Z1, that in equations of two projected ellipses they are the coefficients of yz and xy respectively (not x^2 or y^2 etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A system with approximate (`Real`) coefficients sometimes has only approximate solutions.  Minimizing the norm of the residuals, approach 3 below, may be the best way to approximate the solutions.   In this case, we have seven equations in six unknowns.

```
equations = {
   β1 - (β2 β3)/α1 == 0.1867,
   α2 - (β3 β3)/α1 == 1.9867,
   α3 - (β2 β2)/α1 == 0.9867,
   α1 - (β2 β2)/α3 == 2.96,
   α2 - (β1 β1)/α3 == 1.96,
   β3 - (β1 β2)/α3 == 0.16,
   (4/3*Pi)^2 == 1.743^2*(CharacteristicPolynomial[M, x] /. x -> 0)};
forms = equations /.  Equal -> Subtract; (* differences between the sides of the equations *)
variables = Variables[forms]
(*
{α1, α2, α3, β1, β2, β3}
*)
```

The OP mentioned in a comment that the first six are dependent, but this is true only approximately so.  It seems that `NSolve` thinks that they are independent and, as a result, inconsistent.  (The functions in `forms` were introduced for purposes that become clear below; the system of equations is equivalent to `forms == 0`.)

A few approaches come to mind:

1. Try to increase the tolerance so that `NSolve` solves the system as intended.
2. Omit one of the equations, solve the complementary system, and select solutions that are approximate solutions of the omitted equation.
3. Minimize the distance between the two sides of the equations.

**Approach 1**

I was unsuccessful. There are several avenues (e.g., precision,  the system option `"NSolveOptions" -> {"Tolerance" -> tol}`, `` Internal`$EqualTolerance ``), but I could find no combination of them that worked.

**Approach 2**

One can drop an equation with [`Drop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Drop.html).  It turns out that the first equation is dependent on the rest and may be dropped.  *[Edit]* Following [Daniel Lichtblau's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) advice in a comment, we can add a condition, `Abs@forms[[1]] < 0.0001`, that the first equation be satisfied within a certain tolerance, say, `0.0001`.  Then we get two solutions:

```
sols = NSolve[Append[Drop[equations, 1], Abs@forms[[1]] < 0.0001], variables]
(*
{{α1 -> 2.99959, α2 -> 1.99187, α3 -> 0.999897, β1 -> 0.178501, β2 -> -0.198961, β3 -> 0.124482},
 {α1 -> 2.99959, α2 -> 2.00001, α3 -> 0.999897, β1 -> 0.20001, β2 -> 0.198961, β3 -> 0.199798}}
*)
```

One drawback is that the chosen equation to be dropped will be approximately satisfied while the rest are satisfied exactly.  Indeed all the error is forced on the chosen equation.  Minimizing the norm of the residuals is probably to be preferred, since it shares out the error.  This is done below in approach 3 by processing the results of this section.

**Approach 3**

Here we want to minimize the distance between the two sides.  Thus our objective function could be

```
forms^2 // Total
```

Or perhaps better, we could scale `forms` by the magnitude of the gradients at the solutions, given by

```
df = ComplexExpand /@ Norm /@ D[forms, {variables}];
```

So that the objective function would be each of the following (for each respective solution):

```
(forms^2).(1/df /. sols2[[1]])
(forms^2).(1/df /. sols2[[2]])
```

The best way to proceed is to start with the approximate solutions found in Approach 2.  One might use `NMinimize`, but that would turn out to be less satisfactory (see below).  Instead let's use [`FindArgMin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindArgMin.html).  We can use each solution found above as a starting point:

```
FindMinimum[(forms^2).(1/df /. #), List @@@ #] & /@ sols2
(*
{{2.99957, 1.99186, 0.999892, 0.178447, -0.198922, 0.124498},
 {2.99957, 2., 0.999892, 0.199952, 0.198922, 0.199778}}
*)
```

Or if you want a [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html):

```
Thread /@ (variables -> # &) /@ % 
(*
{{α1 -> 2.99957, α2 -> 1.99186, α3 -> 0.999892, β1 -> 0.178447, β2 -> -0.198922, β3 -> 0.124498},
 {α1 -> 2.99957, α2 -> 2., α3 -> 0.999892, β1 -> 0.199952, β2 -> 0.198922, β3 -> 0.199778}}
*)
```

*Remark:* `NMinimize` might seem like a good approach but it returns only one result.  With luck, one might coax it to return different results by tweaking the methods, their parameters, or by using the `"RandomSearch"` method with different random seeds.  But one would not know when to stop except by analyzing the system as in Approach 2.

Comment: Very nice (I think I am the first upvote). At some point I may need to investigate why the `Tolerance` method is coming up short. (I had of course also tried that, and got nowhere.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks.  I was hoping you would know how to use the tolerance option. Ah, well...

Comment: I think I know how to use it. I just can't beat a better result out of it. Alas.

Comment: The suggestions there seem fine. A third camera or some other independent measurement can be used to exclude one of the two solutions.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for your helpful answer, as you know, the Right Hand Side (RHS) values in question are just an example here and they may change in next situations (for next frames of droplets). Which approach (2 or 3) is more suitable to use in my code in order to converge to the correct answer(s) with all **different** RHS values? Thanks again

Comment: @Hossein As I said, I think the best way to proceed is to start with the approximate solutions found in approach 2 and apply approach 3. Unless you're sure the approximate solutions of 2 are close enough, in which case you can save time by skipping 3.  In other words, I think 3, which is basically to minimize a certain error measure, improves the results of 2.  You could also use your own error measure that reflects the sensitivity of your objective to the parameters.  E.g., if the result is highly sensitive to small changes in `α1`, then weight `α1` more.  I hope that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 3):

I finally got a chance to look into the tolerancing. It seems that there is a fairly narrow window for which `NSolve`, with a nondefault tolerance setting, will handle this.

```
mat = {{a1, b3, b2}, {b3, a2, b1}, {b2, b1, a3}};
eqns = {
       b1 - (b2 b3)/a1 == 0.1867, 
       a2 - (b3 b3)/a1 == 1.9867, 
       a3 - (b2 b2)/a1 == 0.9867, 
       a1 - (b2 b2)/a3 == 2.96, 
       a2 - (b1 b1)/a3 == 1.96, 
       b3 - (b1 b2)/a3 == 0.16, 
       (4/3*Pi)^2 == 1.743^2*(CharacteristicPolynomial[mat, x] /. x -> 0)};

SetSystemOptions["NSolveOptions"->{"Tolerance"->{10^(-4),10^(-2)}}];
```

Roughly, this will clip individual polynomial terms that are made a factor of 10^(-4) smaller during the reduction process (in `GroebnerBasis`, to be technical). It will also entirely remove polynomials when ALL terms have been reduced by a factor of 10^(-2). With this setting:

```
NSolve[eqns, {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3}]

(* Out[176]//InputForm= 
{{a1 -> 2.9995896242394378, a2 -> 1.9999796638931548, a3 -> 0.9998969872422477, 
  b1 -> 0.19992449742212776, b2 -> 0.19896116707304107, 
  b3 -> 0.19978673137863223}, {a1 -> 2.9995896242394378, 
  a2 -> 1.9918501376365532, a3 -> 0.9998969872422477, 
  b1 -> 0.17846968017618514, b2 -> -0.19896116707304115, 
  b3 -> 0.1244932279986043}} *)
```

I think it would be correct to say that this is not the best method for the situation at hand, as it relies too heavily on a difficult-to-predict interplay between tolerance settings that only seem to be useful in a very narrow range. In hindsight we have some idea of what range to look in, since, a posteriori, we have an idea of the sizes if residuals from the approximate solutions. But that's not of much help when one does not already know the answer. In that case about the best to be done is to base tolerances on some measure of the estimated experimental error that gave rise to the equation coefficients.

Comment: Dear Daniel, Thanks for your helpful answer. As you know, the Right Hand Side (RHS) values in question are just an example here and they may change in next situations (for next droplets frames). Is there any way that I can calculate that based on my RHS values, which Tolerance is suitable to use in order to converge to the correct answer(s)? If not, what is your suggestion for me to be able to solve a system while RHS values vary? Thanks again

Comment: I think the method of Approach 2 proposed by @Michael E2 is likely to be the most reliable in general.