# How to find the roots of a very big equation. and why NSolve fails to extract the roots

Tags: equation-solving

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Clear[b]
L = 1;
z[1] = L/4;
z[2] = (2*L)/4;
z[3] = (3*L)/4;
Y = 2*10^11;(*Youngs modulus *)
Iyy = 8.333*10^-6;(*area moment of inertia*)
A = 0.1^2;(*cross sectional area*)
mass = 1; (*mass at the free end of the cantielver*)
ρ = 7850;
n = 3; (* number of springs *)
W[1] = a[1]*Sin[b*x] + a[2]*Cos[b*x] + a[3]*Sinh[b*x] + a[4]*Cosh[b*x];
W[2] = a[5]*Sin[b*x] + a[6]*Cos[b*x] + a[7]*Sinh[b*x] + a[8]*Cosh[b*x];
W[3] = a[9]*Sin[b*x] + a[10]*Cos[b*x] + a[11]*Sinh[b*x] + 
   a[12]*Cosh[b*x];
W[4] = a[13]*Sin[b*(x - z[3])] + a[14]*Cos[b*(x - z[3])] + 
   a[15]*Sinh[b*(x - z[3])] + a[16]*Cosh[b*(x - z[3])];
w = Piecewise[{{W[1], x <= z[1]}, {W[2], z[1] <= x < z[2]}, {W[3], 
     z[2] <= x < z[3]}, {W[4], x > z[3]}}];

(*CANTILEVER BC*)
boundary[i_, j_] := 
 Module[ {bc}, 
  bc1 = {W[i] /. {x -> 0}, (D[W[i], {x, 1}]) /. {x -> 0}, (D[
       W[j], {x, 2}]) /. {x -> L}, ((D[W[j], {x, 3}]) /. {x -> L})}; 
  bc = bc1]

countinuity[i_, j_] := 
 Module[{eq}, 
  eq1 = {((W[i] /. x -> z[i]) - (W[j] /. 
        x -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x}]) /. 
        x -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x}]) /. 
        x -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x, 2}]) /. 
        x -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x, 2}]) /. 
        x -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x, 3}]) /. 
         x -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x, 3}]) /. x -> z[i])) + (K[i]*
        W[i] /. x -> z[i])}; eq = eq1 ]

e1 = boundary[1, 4];
e2 = countinuity[1, 2];
e3 = countinuity[2, 3];
e4 = countinuity[3, 4];
comb = Tuples[{0, 1*^12}, 3];
eq = Flatten[{e1, e2, e3, e4}];
var = Table[a[i], {i, 1, Length[eq]}];
R = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eq, var][[2]];
MatrixForm[R]
K[1] = 0; K[2] = 0; K[3] = 0;
P = Det[R]
s1 = P; 
Plot[s1, {b, 0, 10}]
s2 = NSolve[s1 == 0 && 0 < b < 30]
```

I have a matrix whose dimension is 16 cross 16. I have take a determinant of that matix which leads to very huge equation and it is transcendental in nature. I wanted to find the roots of this equation, for that I used NSolve, but it is not giving me nay results. what are the other ways to extract the roots. and why NSolve fails for these kind of equation.

Comment: Please do not include extraneous code.

Comment: Change the definition of `s1` to `s1 = P // Simplify;` Note the difference in the complexity of the expressions; `LeafCount /@ {P, s1}` evaluates to `{7590, 12}`. In addition to improving efficiency it will also improve precision of calculations. Compare the precision for  `P /. b -> 10.\`15 // FullForm` with `s1 /. b -> 10.\`15 // FullForm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you restrict the range of b NSolve can solve your problem

```
NSolve[{s1 == 0, 1 < b < 10}, b]
{{b -> 1.8751}, {b -> 4.69409}, {b -> 7.85476}}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @BobHanlon has shown there is a "simple" solution to the specific problem.  As for the OP's question "Why," I was taken in by the numerical behavior of `s1`, the inability of `WorkingPrecision` in `NSolve` to resolve the problem, and the trick I used to post-process the `NSolve` results.

The trouble doesn't seem to have to do with the numerics of evaluating `s1` per se, although 16-28 digits are lost for `b` ranging from `14.1` to `23.6` and the derivative at the roots range from `10^35` to `10^45`.  This is where the trouble begins and is likely the principal cause of the failure of `NSolve`; however, evaluating `s1` at high precision produces smoothly changing values, and `FindRoot` has no trouble finding the roots.  The trouble must lie in the internal algorithm used by `NSolve`, which is unknown (to me).

The "trick" is to effectively use a lower "PrecisionGoal" by reducing the precision of the result returned by `NSolve` and removing duplicate roots.  `NSolve` does not have `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` options.  It does have an option [`Method -> {"Tolerance" -> <number(s)>}`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64812/4999), but it's not clear that it can be applied here.  I'll leave the answer, since I do not think this approach has been shown on this site.

---

Higher working precision helps, especially for `b > 8` (it is obvious in the plot that round-off error dominates at greater values of `b`).  In this case, numerical noise in the last few digits, at whatever `WorkingPrecsion`, means several roots show up multiple times at slightly different locations.  Lowering the final precision makes these roots the same.

```
s2 = DeleteDuplicates@ N@ NSolve[s1 == 0 && 0 < b < 30, WorkingPrecision -> 32]
(*
  {{b -> 1.8751},  {b -> 4.69409}, {b -> 7.85476}, {b -> 10.9955},
   {b -> 14.1372}, {b -> 17.2788}, {b -> 20.4204}, {b -> 23.5619}}
*)
```

Comment: In a way, if I define the working precision I can get the roots. Is that  what you are saying

Comment: Changing the definition of `s1` to `s1 = P // Simplify` enables use of machine precision. `s2 = NSolve[s1 == 0 && 0 < b < 30]` and will give the **ten** roots in the interval `{0, 30}`

Comment: But there are some roots which get repeated, and I used DeleteDuplicates[b/.s2], but could not able to remove the duplicates.

Comment: With v11.3 on my Mac and the revised definition of `s1` (i.e., including `Simplify`), `s2 = NSolve[s1 == 0 && 0 < b < 30]` evaluates to 

`{{b -> 1.8751}, {b -> 4.69409}, {b -> 7.85476}, {b -> 10.9955}, {b -> 
   14.1372}, {b -> 17.2788}, {b -> 20.4204}, {b -> 23.5619}, {b -> 
   26.7035}, {b -> 29.8451}}` There are no duplicate roots.

Answer (score 2):

```
s1 = P // Simplify

(* 128 b^24 (1 + Cos[b] Cosh[b]) *)
```

The exact solutions are expressed as [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects

```
(s2 = Solve[{s1 == 0, 0 < b < 30}]) // Column
```

[image]

The approximate numerical roots are

```
s2 // N

(* {{b -> 1.8751}, {b -> 4.69409}, {b -> 7.85476}, {b -> 10.9955}, {b -> 
   14.1372}, {b -> 17.2788}, {b -> 20.4204}, {b -> 23.5619}, {b -> 
   26.7035}, {b -> 29.8451}} *)
```

Comment: Bob, This is even faster. I never tried using Solve for a transcendental equation in Mathematica. Thanks a lot.  Actually, the thing is K[1], K[2], K[3] are the three defined variables. these variables take two values 0 and infinity. If I take a combination of these variables there are 8 such combinations. I have written a code but seems like it running forever.  can you give me some input to implement this properly.

Comment: Nice. Bursts my balloon, though.  This was the first time I recall `NSolve` finding multiple roots at a simple root because of numerical noise. But now it seems unnecessary.

Comment: If any `K[n]` is `Infinity` then `Det[R]` will be infinite and your problem cannot be solved as posed. Perhaps you mean `K[n]` can be extremely large and you want to look at the behavior in that case. Let the non-zero value be the variable `inf`. Then the term with the highest order of 'inf' will dominate. Perhaps what you want is `NSolve[{CoefficientList[Det[R /. kValues] // FullSimplify, inf][[-1]] == 0,
   0 < b < 30}, b]`. This will in general be very slow.